# How to play mp4 video on device

Tags: android, video

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse(videofile);
VideoView video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
video.setVideoURI(uri);
video.start();
```

if i play video using this code in android emulator than it working properly but when i run it on device than it throws error..

will u tell me when i click on specific video that video must play on android videoview or by default play in devices video player

Answer (score 1):

If you play it from SD card use this code

```
File clip=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
               "haha.mp4");
if (clip.exists()) {
 video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
 video.setVideoPath(clip.getAbsolutePath());

 ctlr=new MediaController(this);
 ctlr.setMediaPlayer(video);
 video.setMediaController(ctlr);
 video.requestFocus();
 video.start();
}
```

And if you play video from online use this inside manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```